# No Script Tag - reliable? Secure?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

I have built a small app using javascript.  I am using javascript for form validation and i am wondering if by using the "no script" tag if this will protect me against people passing non-clean data into my mysql db?  I will deny access to the application to anyone who has it turned off.  Is this a secure method or do i have to also do php form validation on top of the js validation?

If not, can someone advise me on what is the best way to ensure that the data submitted to my db is not harmful and clean. Id like to do this using javascipt if possible and not layer it with php but if i have to i will as long as my app is secure.

I know i must do some php cleaning such as htmlentities but want to avoid doing form validation with php.

Thanks.

Comment: For what reason you want to avoid doing form validation with php?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you can never trust the client-side to validate. You must always validate server-side. Client-side validation can improve the user experience, but it gives no security benefit.

Comment: I kind of figured that, i was just being lazy and thought id ask. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

As a general rule, you never want to rely on client-side code (javascript in this case) to validate data. The client has full control over anything you would put in javascript, and so it would be pretty easy to bypass. Always validate on the server where you have full control of what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

No, you always need to do serverside validation. You can alter JS even when it's turned on (in Chrome for example, you can just pause script loading, edit the JS then run it), therefore it wouldn't even matter if it's on or not.

This is a good starting point: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/build-a-neat-html5-powered-contact-form/ (towards the bottom is the validation examples)

Answer (score 1):

Javascript protection is just "visual". Anyone can bypass it and insert any data he/she wants.

You should always validate user-submitted data server-side.

Basically you can start with mysql_real_escape_string() for preventing mysql injection, and do some tag stripping if you are going to display the inputted data back.